# Failed to save CF_UC_NRI_Details.cmp: c:CF_UC_NRI_Details:3,125: Invalid attribute "implements": Source

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute

<aura:component >

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    
 <aura:attribute name="sectionTitle" type="String" required="true" access="public" 
                description="Section title" />
    
    <div class="cfcontainer">
        
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-size--1-of-1">
                <div class="slds-m-bottom--small slds-section-title--divider sectionTitle">
                    {!v.sectionTitle} 
                </div>
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap fieldContainer">
                    <lightning:select name="NRI" label="NRI Customer" required="true">
                        <option value="">None</option>
                        <option value="1">Yes</option>
                        <option value="2">No</option>
                    </lightning:select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a simple typo!

You have `<aura:component>` tag twice in the beginning.

Ensure you have proper markup with one `<aura:component>` tag opening at the beginning and closing at the end.